# How to expand in taylor series a composition of functions?

Tags: maxima, taylor-series

I would like to expand in taylor series a function of type : `f(x+f(x))` around `x=a` in the case where `f(a)=0`.

```
(%i1) atvalue(f(x),[x=a],0)$
```

The direct calculus yields :

```
(%i2) taylor(f(x+f(x)),x,a,2);

(%o2)/T/ f(a)+(at('diff(f(f(x)+x),x,1),x=a))*(x-a)+((at('diff(f(f(x)+x),x,2),x=a))*(x-a)^2)/2+...
```

If I define a intermediate function :

```
(%i3)define(tf(x),taylor(f(x),x,a,2))$
```

Then a expand in Taylor series I get :

```
(%i4) taylor(f(x+tf(x)),x,a,2);

(%o4) 0+...
```

I expect the following result : 
`f(1+f'(a))f'(a)(x-a)+(x-a)^2 f''(a)[f'(a)+(1+f'(a))^2/2]+o(x-a)^2`

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gradef` to simplify notation.

```
gradef(f(x),  f1(x)) $
gradef(f1(x), f2(x)) $

atvalue(f(x), x = a,  0) $

e: f(x+f(x)) $
e: taylor(e, x, a, 2) $
e: expand(e, 0, 0)$ /* 'taylor' form to ordinar expression */
e: ev(e, nouns);    /* f(a) to 0 */
```

returns

```
          2                                          2
       (f1 (a) f2(a) + 3 f1(a) f2(a) + f2(a)) (x - a)
(%o7) -----------------------------------------------
                              2
                                                          2
                                                     + (f1 (a) + f1(a)) (x - a)
```

Comment: ok it's clear in this case! However is it possible to evaluate the simplification f(a)=0 in the taylor expansion? It could be usefull for example if I want to expand in taylor series the function 1/f(x+f(x))

Answer (score 0):

A solution is as follow :

```
    gradef(f(x),  f1(x)) $
    gradef(f1(x), f2(x)) $
    atvalue(f(x), x = a,  0) $

    e: f(x+f(x)) $
    e: taylor(e, x, a, 2) $
    e: expand(e, 0, 0)$ /* 'taylor' form to ordinar expression*/
    e: ev(e, nouns);    /* f(a) to 0 */
    taylor(e,x,a,2); /* Becomes again a taylor serie which could be reused*/
```

For example, if I want to find the order of the [Steffensen method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffensen%27s_method) which is defined, for function f which is C^2 and f(a)=0,f'(a)!=0, by :

```
    Sf(x)=x-f(x)^2/(f(x+f(x)-f(x))
```

If I straight expand this function around a I get :

```
Sf(x)=a+(x-a)-(f1(a)^2*(x-a)^2)/f(a)+...
```

which diverges since f(a)=0.

So this must be proceed in two steps. First I expand the denominator :

```
    den:f(x+f(x))-f(x)$
    t:taylor(den,x,a,2);
    t: expand(t, 0, 0)$
    t: ev(t, nouns)$
    t:taylor(t,x,a,2);
```

Then I expand the function Sf:

```
    Sf:x-f(x)^2/(t)$/*Introducing the taylor serie of den*/
    taylor(Sf,x,a,2);
```

which provides the wanted result :

```
    Sf(x)=a+((f1(a)+1)*f2(a)*(x-a)^2)/(2*f1(a))+...
```